# Read blob field in core/session table

Tags: php, session, core-session

**EDIT**
Sorry, I have formulated my question extremely badly: I need to retrieve this field(no problem) and read the value with php(problem, I haven't ever met this type of input and I don't know howto handle it)

I need to retrieved `session_data` field from the table `core_session` and read the value with php? 
From PhpMyAdminField structure:

```
session_data    mediumblob
```

and it lets me download it like a `.bin` file.
I know it isn't fully related to Magento, but maybe here someone has got a better idea on how the whole session storage process works.

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188264/viewing-content-of-blob-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: @RobMangiafico My is about how to read that field, I thought that the fact that phpmyadmin shows it as as a bin file could be an useful information, this is the first time I handle this type of data

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a better mysql client:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools